# Implementation in C# for PBKDF2 For Php

Tags: c#, php, hash

I'm in the process of converting PHP code to C#.net and one of the task is hashing for passwords.

PHP is using PBKDF2 For PHP (https://defuse.ca/php-pbkdf2.htm) and after quite a search I managed to write a code which does hashing but I'm not able to verify existing passwords with my approach. I need help in understanding what I'm missing.

PHP Code

```
function pbkdf2($algorithm, $password, $salt, $count, $key_length, $raw_output = false)
{
    $algorithm = strtolower($algorithm);
    if(!in_array($algorithm, hash_algos(), true))
        trigger_error('PBKDF2 ERROR: Invalid hash algorithm.', E_USER_ERROR);
    if($count <= 0 || $key_length <= 0)
        trigger_error('PBKDF2 ERROR: Invalid parameters.', E_USER_ERROR);

    if (function_exists("hash_pbkdf2")) {
        // The output length is in NIBBLES (4-bits) if $raw_output is false!
        if (!$raw_output) {
            $key_length = $key_length * 2;
        }
        return hash_pbkdf2($algorithm, $password, $salt, $count, $key_length, $raw_output);
    }

    $hash_length = strlen(hash($algorithm, "", true));
    $block_count = ceil($key_length / $hash_length);

    $output = "";
    for($i = 1; $i <= $block_count; $i++) {
        // $i encoded as 4 bytes, big endian.
        $last = $salt . pack("N", $i);
        // first iteration
        $last = $xorsum = hash_hmac($algorithm, $last, $password, true);
        // perform the other $count - 1 iterations
        for ($j = 1; $j < $count; $j++) {
            $xorsum ^= ($last = hash_hmac($algorithm, $last, $password, true));
        }
        $output .= $xorsum;
    }

    if($raw_output)
        return substr($output, 0, $key_length);
    else
        return bin2hex(substr($output, 0, $key_length));
}
```

and C# implementation is

```
    public static string ComputePBKDF2(string algorithm, string password, byte[] salt, int count, int keyLength, bool rawOutput = false)
{
    algorithm = algorithm.ToLower();

    if (count <= 0 || keyLength <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid parameters.");

    if (CryptoConfig.AllowOnlyFipsAlgorithms && !algorithm.StartsWith("hmac", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        algorithm = "hmacsha256"; // Default to HMAC-SHA-256 for FIPS compliance

    using (Rfc2898DeriveBytes pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt, count))
    {
        //pbkdf2. = keyLength; // Set the key length
        byte[] derivedKey = pbkdf2.GetBytes(keyLength);

        if (rawOutput)
        {
            return Convert.ToBase64String(derivedKey);
        }
        else
        {
            return BitConverter.ToString(derivedKey).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
        }
    }
}
```

I've also tried the following method but both of them failed to verify the password

```
    public static byte[] ComputePBKDF2(string algorithm, string password, byte[] salt, int count, int keyLength)
{
    using (SHA256 hmac = SHA256.Create(algorithm))
    {
        int hashLength = (hmac.HashSize + 7) / 8; // Length of the hash in bytes
        int blockCount = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)keyLength / hashLength);

        byte[] output = new byte[keyLength];
        byte[] last = salt;

        for (int i = 0; i < blockCount; i++)
        {
            byte[] iter = BitConverter.GetBytes(i + 1); // $i encoded as 4 bytes, big endian
            Array.Reverse(iter); // Convert to big-endian

            byte[] xorSum = hmac.ComputeHash(last);
            last = xorSum;

            for (int j = 1; j < count; j++)
            {
                byte[] iterHmac = hmac.ComputeHash(last);
                last = iterHmac;

                for (int k = 0; k < xorSum.Length; k++)
                {
                    xorSum[k] ^= iterHmac[k];
                }
            }

            Array.Copy(xorSum, 0, output, i * hashLength, Math.Min(hashLength, keyLength - i * hashLength));
        }

        return output;
    }
}
```

To verify it I'm calling the funciton with password and the hash value

```
VerifyPassword("Nouman@2023!", "sha256:1000:DlrSWdE5PFiP7MiMPUD98rwYobnDp56+:dDh1pxHduY9iw5uGFowNWncNfhPXWGDB")
```

and the method to verify is

```
    public static bool VerifyPassword(string password, string correctHash)
{
    int HASH_SECTIONS = 4;
    int HASH_ALGORITHM_INDEX = 0;
    int HASH_ITERATION_INDEX = 1;
    int HASH_SALT_INDEX = 2;
    int HASH_PBKDF2_INDEX = 3;
    string[] hassSplit = correctHash.Split(':');

    if (hassSplit.Length < HASH_SECTIONS)
        return false;

    byte[] pbkdf2 = Convert.FromBase64String(hassSplit[HASH_PBKDF2_INDEX]);
    byte[] salt = new byte[24];
    salt = Convert.FromBase64String(hassSplit[HASH_SALT_INDEX]);

    string result = ComputePBKDF2(hassSplit[HASH_ALGORITHM_INDEX], password, salt, int.Parse(hassSplit[HASH_ITERATION_INDEX]), pbkdf2.Length,true);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
    byte[] computedHash = Convert.FromBase64String(result.);
    
    return slowEquals(pbkdf2, computedHash);
    
}

private static bool slowEquals(byte[] a, byte[] b)
{
    uint diff = (uint)a.Length ^ (uint)b.Length;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length && i < b.Length; i++)
    {
        diff |= (uint)(a[i] ^ b[i]);
    }
    return diff == 0;
}
```

Comment: If there is no specific reason for writing your own implementation, you might consider using [Rfc2898DeriveBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes?view=net-7.0) class.

Comment: I'm using it in the first version but it doesn't validate the password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I break this code into smaller parts to solve this, which are;

- Generate Salt
- Create Hash
- Validate existing hash
- Create new hash which could also be validated by the same method

so for generating Salth, In C#, Initially I used the `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` class to generate cryptographically secure random bytes, which is the equivalent of `mcrypt_create_iv` with `MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM` in PHP. Here's how I used it initially in C#:

```
int PBKDF2_SALT_BYTE_SIZE = 24; // You can adjust the size to your requirements
byte[] salt = new byte[PBKDF2_SALT_BYTE_SIZE];
using (RNGCryptoServiceProvider rngCsp = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
{
    rngCsp.GetBytes(salt);
}
```

The more latest way to do tis is to use `RandomNumberGenerator` class

```
// Generate a salt
byte[] salt = RandomNumberGenerator.GetBytes(PBKDF2_SALT_BYTE_SIZE);
```

In PHP code the main method being used to generate the hash is `hash_pbkdf2`. In C#, I used the `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` class to perform the equivalent of `hash_pbkdf2` in PHP. Here's how I use it:

```
// Generate the hash
Rfc2898DeriveBytes pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes("PasswordToHash", Convert.ToBase64String(salt), PBKDF2_ITERATIONS,HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);
byte[] hash = pbkdf2.GetBytes(PBKDF2_HASH_BYTE_SIZE);
```

The most important thing to note in this is the Hash algo name passed in the constructor. By default this class uses SHA1. The other thing to note is I've to use `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes` for salt on top of `Convert.ToBase64String`. If I don't use this than the validate function which works for validating the existing hash will not work for new password hash.

Now the validate part. I don't need to write any slowequal method for it. Built in C# function `CryptographicOperations.FixedTimeEquals` does the trick

```
public static bool Validate(string passwordHash, string password)
{
    Console.WriteLine(HashAlgorithmName.SHA256.ToString().ToLower());
    char[] delimiter = { ':' };
    var pwdElements = passwordHash.Split(delimiter);
    //var salt = Convert.FromBase64String(pwdElements[2]);
    var hash = Convert.FromBase64String(pwdElements[3]);
    byte[] saltBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(pwdElements[2]);
    var hashInput = Rfc2898DeriveBytes.Pbkdf2(password, saltBytes, 1000, _hashAlgorithmName, 24);

    Console.WriteLine("saved hash: " + Convert.ToHexString(hash));
    Console.WriteLine("generated hash: " + Convert.ToHexString(hashInput));

    return CryptographicOperations.FixedTimeEquals( hashInput, hash);
}
```

this code validates the new hash and the existing hashes also.